# Is there a way to pass the result of a function to a jquery function as an argument

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of jquery code to add onClick functionality to a button. This uses another class - ROButton - to handle the functionality. ROButton looks as follows (with certain details redacted as they are needlessly complex):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        ROButton: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                onClick : function() { return false; },
                lockout : true,
                self: this
            };
            options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).button().on("click", function() {
                    if (options.onClick() !== false && options.lockout) {
                        //Specialized lockout code
                        options = defaults;
                      }
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Attaching this to a button is done as follows:

```
$("button.saveBtn").ROButton({
            onClick: function() {
                //onClick details
            }
        , lockout: false });
```

I would like to be able to use the result of another function as the value of the lockout argument. I have tried as follows:

```
$("button.saveBtn").ROButton({
            onClick: function() {
                //onClick details
            }
        , lockout: flagFunction() });
```

However this does not seem to work as expected. Regardless of the return value of flagFunction - which itself works correctly and is used elsewhere - this does not seem to be passing the expected boolean value through. Is there any way to do what I'm trying to?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is `flagFunction()` synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: your code as posted will work, provided flagFunction is synchronous of course, it will be run straight away, what value is given to lockout?

Comment: If the value returned by flagfunction changes then you need to call it inside your button click handler, or you will be looking at an outdated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `options.lockout` is a function, and call it to get the value.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    ROButton: function(options) {
      var defaults = {
        onClick: function() {
          return false;
        },
        lockout: true,
        self: this
      };
      options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
      return this.each(function() {
        $(this).button().on("click", function() {
          let lockout = typeof options.lockout == 'function' ? options.lockout() : options.lockout;
          if (options.onClick() !== false && lockout) {
            //Specialized lockout code
            options = defaults;
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

When you call the function, you should just pass a reference to the callback function, not call it immediately.

```
$("button.saveBtn").ROButton({
  onClick: function() {
    //onClick details
  },
  lockout: flagFunction
});
```

Comment: This would also need a change to how `ROButton` is called `lockout: flagFunction,` (ie without `()`)